# Beutiful soup how to get the address of the destination which an image link point to?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My python version is 3.4.1 and beautiful soup version is 4.3.2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hiSn.jpg
I want to get the image target's href
but it can't display anything
The following is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?hl=zh-TW#hl=zh-TW&q=lol"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
for link in soup.find_all('h3' ,attrs={'class': 'r'}):
    print (link.get('href'))
```

Comment: the reason you don't get results is because google is playing tricks on you (blocking automated requests)

Comment: He can easliy check that with printing the soup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except that my source of the url doesn't contain an 'h3' tag, this version works for me with python 2.7 though.

```
for tag in soup.findAll("a", {'class': 'gb1'}):
     print(tag["href"])
```